# "Width" of symmetric groups

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, probability-distributions

For any (finite) group $G$ define *length* $l(G)$ as length of maximal chain of proper subgroups (it's known and pretty widely used invariant). But we can also define *width* function $w_G(n)$ in such fashion: $w_G(n) := \#\{H<G: l(H) = n\}$. Then we can do some adjustments — make it a function $W_G:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ by setting $W_G(k/l(G)) = w_G(k)$, interpolating linearly and then maybe normalizing by setting integral over $[0, 1]$ to $1$. For example, $W_{\Bbb Z/n}$ is constant and $W_{\Bbb Z/p^k}$ is $p$-binomial distribution.

So, my question is: what is limit of $W_{S_n}$ for large $n$? Is it dominated  by $W_{Syl_2(S_n)}$? (Exact length of $S_n$ is known (Cameron-Solomon-Turull, 1989) and asymptotically equal to length of 2-Sylow.)